# The distribution of the number of time an asymmetric Brownian Motion or Random Walk across zero

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, brownian-motion, random-walk

We know that for an asymmetric random walk or Brownian motion with drift, then it will across zero finitely often. I want to know that if I am looking at the following random variable

$$ M =\mbox{Number of times the process across 0 }$$

where "the process" refers to asymmetric random walk or Brownian motion with drift with time $t\in[0,+\infty)$, then what is the support of $M$? Is it finite? And what is the distribution of $M$?

Intuitively, what does it mean that the process across zero finitely often? Does it mean, this process can cross the zero $1,2,3,...n,...$ times, but the corresponding probability goes to 0 as $n$ goes to infinity? But then, this means the support of this random variable $M$ is still infinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the random walk crosses zero finitely often, simply means that $\mathbb P[M=\infty]=0$. But it does not mean that the support of $M$ is finite. In fact, $M$ has a geometric distribution, as shown below.

Let $0=S_0,S_1,S_2,\ldots$ be an asymmetric random walk such that  $\mathbb P[S_1=1]=p$ and $\mathbb P[S_1=-1]=1-p$. Assume $p>\frac 1 2$. Exercise 1.13 of [Durret's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=evbGTPhuvSoC&source=gbs_navlinks_s) shows that $\mathbb P[M=0] = p(2p-1)=:q$. Now, the fact that $M$ has a geometric distribution follows from noting that $M=k$ if and only if the random walk returns to zero $k$ times and does not return to zero afterwards, hence, $\mathbb P[M=k]=(1-q)^k q$. This is true for any *transient Markov chain* (see Theorem 3.1 of [Durret's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=evbGTPhuvSoC&source=gbs_navlinks_s)).

For the Brownian motion, the number of returns to zero is necessarily infinite. But you might be interested in the [local time at zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_time_(mathematics)). By the [invariance principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem), I guess that the local time has an exponential distribution.

Comment: +1.  You can also say that if the probability of starting at $0$ and never again crossing $0$  is $q$ then $\mathbb P(M\ge k) = (1-q)\mathbb P(M\ge k-1) =(1-q)^k$